# How to import boofcv jar files into a java project from cmd?

Tags: cmd, jar, classpath, jython, boofcv

I am trying to see if I can use BoofCV from Jython. So I already have written a class in Java which runs from IDE but in order to be able to call the boofcv packages :

```
import boofcv.alg.filter.binary.BinaryImageOps;
import boofcv.alg.filter.binary.Contour;
import boofcv.alg.filter.binary.GThresholdImageOps;
import boofcv.gui.ListDisplayPanel;
import boofcv.gui.binary.VisualizeBinaryData;
import boofcv.gui.image.ShowImages;
import boofcv.io.UtilIO;
import boofcv.io.image.ConvertBufferedImage;
import boofcv.io.image.UtilImageIO;
import boofcv.struct.ConnectRule;
import boofcv.struct.image.GrayS32;
import boofcv.struct.image.GrayU8;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.List;
import boofcv.alg.segmentation.watershed.WatershedVincentSoille1991;
import boofcv.factory.segmentation.FactorySegmentationAlg;
```

I saw that I firstly need to compile my java file with javac. When I am using

```
javac -myfile.java
```

I get errors stating that the corresponding boofcv packages do not exist. So I used this command:

```
  javac -cp "./dir/boofcv-io-0.31.jar" myjavafile.java
```

to see if at least the package boofcv.io will be used properly but still says that does not exist.

Any idea why? I am getting something wrong?

Comment: Actually seeing the errors you mention can be quite helpful.  Also, what happens when you execute `ls ./dir/boofcv-io-0.31.jar`?